# How to change the frontend model for an customer attribute?

Tags: magento-1.8

I have the following issue, I added a `datetime` attribute for the `customer` entity. In database I save the value in `GMT`, but on `customer info` tab I want the time to be converted to store time.

When I use the `text` frontend type The time is shown in GMT, I want to create a custom type that is converting the time to the store time before showing.

Comment: can you show your code(customer attribute)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use source model for that attribute**.

so you have create an attribute by this manner

```
$installer->addAttribute('customer','badge', array( 
    'label'             => 'Badge',
    'type'              => 'datetime',    //backend_type
    'input'             => 'date', //frontend_input
    'backend'           => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',    
    'global'            =>  Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'source'            => 'yourmodel/attribute_gmt',
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'default'           => '',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'unique'            => false,
    'note'              => ''
));
```

In that source model only the attribute values are extracted and return to the view.

> app/code/{codepool}/{namespace}/{module}/Model/Attribute/Gmt.php

in `outputValue` function you can do your login and return the value.

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Attribute_Gmt extends Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute_Data_Date
{
    public function outputValue($format = Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute_Data::OUTPUT_FORMAT_TEXT)
    {

        $value = $this->getEntity()->getData($this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode());
        if ($value) {
            // Your logic
            $value = $this->_applyOutputFilter($value);
        }

        $this->_dateFilterFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT);

        return $value;
    }
}
```

Refer this [link](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-custom-attribute-source-type/) you 'll get better understanding of source model

Comment: The ideea is that when i put `date` as frontend input i am losing the hour part... should i go for input_renderer maybe ?

Comment: yes, you can add `'input_renderer'    => 'yourmodel/datetime'` refer this http://inchoo.net/magento/adding-magento-attribute-with-custom-input-renderer/